# Simple AngularJS example with a module and controller in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

This probably a combo jsFiddle/Angular question, but I'm trying to learn me some basic Angular and I'm not sure why it only works when I include the controller JS in the HTML pane.  [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/skube/E9bU5/2/)

Basically the following works:

```
<div ng-app="myAppModule" ng-controller="someController">
<!-- Show the name in the browser -->
 <h1>Welcome {{ name }}</h1>

<p>made by : {{userName}}</p>
<!-- Bind the input to the name -->
<input ng-model="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
</div>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myAppModule', []);
myApp.controller('someController', function($scope) {
    // do some stuff here
    $scope.userName = "skube";
});
</script>
```

But if I try to move the JS within the script tag to the JavaScript pane, it fails.

Comment: `No wrap - in <head>` http://jsfiddle.net/E9bU5/3/

Comment: I swear I tried that, but you're correct.  What does "No wrap - in <head>" mean? It doesn't make sense to me

Comment: jsFiddle wraps your code in a ready or load event by default, and Angular might not find what it needs in the global scope when compiling your template at the time is needed. `No wrap in <head>` just loads the script in the head, without a wrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/) for some info about jsFiddle with Angular

Also more examples on AngularJS Wiki that you could use:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples